# Is there anyway to include certain variables from one php file and receive them in another file?

Tags: php, variables

Is there anyway to include certain variables from one php file and receive them in another file? I know you can include a whole file but in my case the program would not work because the program would try to redirect to user_details.php inside that file. So instead I tried to do `include 'process.php.$username';` in user_details.php but that doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Here is my code:

process.php

```
    $username = $_POST["user"];
    $password = $_POST["pass"];

    $username = stripcslashes($username);
    $password = stripcslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

    mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    mysql_select_db("message_board");

    $result = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'") or die("Failed to query database ".mysql_error());

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    if ($row["username"] == $username and $row["password"] == $password) {
        echo "Login success! Welcome ".$row["username"], " and ".$row["user_permissions"];
        header('location: user_details.php');
    } else {
        echo "Failed to login! \n";
        echo '<a href="login.php">Back to Login</a>';
    }
```

user_details.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>user_details</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <?php
            include 'process.php.$username';
            include 'process.php.$password';

            mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
            mysql_select_db("message_board");

            $result = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '$username' and password = '$password'") or die("Failed to query database ".mysql_error());

            $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            echo "user permissions: ".$row["username"].$row["user_permissions"];
        ?>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ***Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).*** [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` if you just want to keep variables around from page to page.

Comment: ok thanks for that I will look into those. thanks

Comment: Whatever you do, do not go live with this code unless you have a desire for your website to be hacked.

Comment: ok. I am just new to learning php as I have only been using it for 1 or 2 months

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) which will allow you to pass variables between requests (and that means between "files" too).

For example:

**process.php:**

```
<?php
session_start(); // very important - you need to start session!

// do something on database

// assign something to session variable
$_SESSION['data'] = $something;

header('Location: user_details.php');
?>
```

**user_details.php:**

```
<?php
session_start(); // like before

// get variable from session
$data = $_SESSION['data'];

// do something with $data
?>
```

[Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) you can find more about it.

Comment: While these links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: it says undefined index in data for user_details.php when I run the scripts.

Comment: it works now. I just needed to change the variable name in user_details.php